# replace string rsubmit with * rsubmit

Tags: shell, ksh

I have text files with lines like these:

```
--------------------------  
.... 
... rsubmit;  
........  
........ endrsubmit;  
.......  
...... rsubmit ;  
................  
....... endrsubmit ;  
..........  
-----------------------------  

I want to replace  
all 'rsubmit;'     with '* rsubmit;'  
all 'rsubmit ;'    with '* rsubmit ;'  
all 'endrsubmit;'  with '* endrsubmit;'  
all 'endrsubmit ;' with '* endrsubmit ;'
```

In short, just put star-space at the beginning.

I have tried to use sed 's/rsubmit\;/\* rsubmit\;/g'
but this method cannot take care of those 'endrsubmit'

Can any one help on this ?

Thanks
Alvin SIU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sed 's/\(end\)\?rsubmit/* &/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/(.[^ \t]*rsubmit)/,"*\\1")' file
--------------------------
....
...* rsubmit;
........
........* endrsubmit;
.......
......* rsubmit ;
................
.......* endrsubmit ;
..........
-----------------------------
```

Or awk

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i~/rsubmit/) { $i="* "$i } } }1' file
```

Comment: Sorry no ruby in my company.  Also, the rsubmit; and endrsubmit; statement may start at the beginning of the line.